# CSS height not taken from styles sheet

Tags: html, css

I have set height 28px in my css sheet for specific input fields, however the browser sets 30px (see picture). Why is that and how to fix this?

[image]

This is the class definition:

```
.filter-cell > .form-control {
  border: 1px solid rgb(169, 169, 169) !important;
  height: 28px !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px !important;
}
```

Comment: Does this element have padding or margin?

Comment: Please make sure to provide the code otherwise is going to be difficult to give an answer.

Comment: added the css class

Comment: css is not enough. provide a complete working example so it will be possible to see which elements affect other elements and how exactly your html/css is built. you can use jsfiddle/codepen/snippets for that

Comment: no, I call my styles last

Comment: Border increase the height by 1px*2, see my update answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `box-sizing` value that consider or not the padding in the size of your element. Try to add `box-sizing:border-box;` to your element.

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to know more about `box-sizing`.

Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/6vv914oa/1).

P.S. to change the `box-sizing` for the whole document (as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) do) use:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**EDIT**

Also border increase the size of the element so you'll need to set the `height` considering the `border` size, in your case:

```
border: 1px solid rgb(169, 169, 169) !important;
height:26px;
```

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:28px;
  background-color:red;
  padding:1px 0;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.content-box {
  box-sizing:content-box;
}
.border-box {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.border {
  padding:0px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
Ispect those two divs:
<div class="content-box">

</div>

<div class="border-box">

</div>

<div class="border">

</div>
```

Comment: I use Bootstrap so the element already had `box-sizing: border-box`. Any other ideas?